# How to use ZipInputStream(JAVA) in IOS/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, asihttprequest, zipinputstream

I need to read the next ZIP file entry and positions the stream at the beginning of the entry data (ZipInputStream getNextEntry). How to do that in Objective-C/IOS because I want to process the files in zip one by one while it is being downloaded. I have not found any zip libraries to do that.

*Any help would be appreciated*

**Thanks**

Comment: Please provide the code of what you've tried so far :)

Comment: I've tried https://github.com/epatel/pinch-objc, but it will make multiple network requests